# Inject dependencies through initializers (using Storyboards)? [Swift]

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, initialization, uistoryboard

I was wondering whether there is a way to not explicitly have to pass around your dependency object through setters. i.e setter dependencies:

```
var store: Store!
```

Can this somehow be done through the VC's initializer (instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier), i.e. initializer injection with storyboards? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce an extra class, that is responsible for configuring your viewController.

```
class MyViewControllerConfigurator {

    static func configure(viewController: MyViewController) {

        let someDependency = SomeDependency()

        viewController.someDependency = someDependency

        // force trigger lazy initialization of view (and subviews), which would be nil otherwize in awaikFromNib
        _ = viewController.view

        // do further configuration here (add child view controller, set delegates ...)
    }
}
```

Usage in `MyViewController`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        MyViewControllerConfigurator.configure(viewController: self)
    }
}
```

This way your viewController gets configured even when instantiated using Storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I totally forgot about singletons actually.. Haven't use them in a while. But aren't singletons in general bad design as they violate the single responsibility principle?

Comment: I agree avoiding Singletons is a god thing, the reason therefore is not "single responsibility principle" though, but that is another topic. This was just one possible example implementation.  I updated the answer.

Comment: @shallowThought This is not a dependency injection example. You are setting dependency manually and you're not passing the dependency to the target.